# What is the proper way to update an RRule event in FullCalendar 4

Tags: fullcalendar, rrule, fullcalendar-4

I have a FullCalendar with one recurring event, initialized by a RRule string.
You can see a demo on [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-snow-koz06m2op3)
The Calendar is made editable so you can drag an event to a different location.

When the event is dropped, a function is called which is past a `info`parameter.

Examining `info.event.start`I see that the start time of the event has indeed changed.

Now what is the best way to retrieve the RRule string in order to store it in my database? Note that the DTSTART property in the string has to change too!

Comment: well since the value is provided through a property called "rrule", I would expect you can probably find it in `extendedProps.rrule` in your event object. I haven't tried that, but as the documentation says, that's where all extra / non-standard properties are placed after the event is parsed. Have you tried anything to locate it so far?

Comment: No, it's not. I CAN find the RRule Object in `info.event._def.recurringDef.typeData` but I can't imagine that this would be the proper way?

Comment: The proper way would be the after an event is altered, we could retrieve the RRule property, no?

Comment: I see. That's annoying. Maybe it's not meant to be made a public property, for some reason. I don't know what the developers intended. Perhaps you could raise a bug or feature request to get it made available.

Comment: I will do that!

Comment: any updates on this? I also have related issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59358909/events-with-rrule-plugin-is-not-updating-after-drag-drop-on-change-view-grid-ful

Comment: I know 'me toos' aren't welcome.. BUT I wanted to add some noise so that this might get some attention. I see no prescribed way to modify an rrule based event and have the calendar update.